# Divide the 3 Gospels by Year

Tags: john, matthew, luke, mark, gospels

Divide the 3 Gospels by Year of Jesus Ministry

How would you divide the 3 Gospels by year of Jesus ministry?

Gospel of John can be divided between Passover years
year 1 (chapters 1-5) year 2 (chapters 6-11) year 3 (chapters 13-21)

Gospel of Matthew
genealogy (chapter 1) birth (chapter 2) 
start of year 1 (chapters 3-9) ????
start of year 2 (chapters 10-14)????
start of year 3, we know starts around chapter 15 because heading to Jerusalem

Gospel of Mark 
start of year 1 (chapters 1- ) 
start of year 2 (chapters ???) 
start of year 3, we know starts around chapter 1 because heading to Jerusalem (chapters 10- )

Gospel of Luke
Birth (chapters 1-2)
start of year 1 (3-)
start of year 2 ()
start of year 3, we know starts around chapter 13 because heading to Jerusalem (13-)

Hoping to start a discipleship program divided by year, the same way Jesus discipled His disciples through the years, while using epistles as supporting scripture to Gospels, since most of text in epistles points back to Gospels.

Thanks for your input. Much appreciated

Comment: There are a few different harmonies of the Gospels out there that do this, I think.  I personally recommend the Gospel commentary of the Eastern Orthodox Archbishop Averky Tauchev, who follows more or less the [Diatessaron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatessaron).  Averky's book is available on [Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/Four-Gospels-Commentary-Holy-Scriptures-ebook/dp/B011H5IDTQ).  The Kindle edition is $12 - a very good investment in my opinion.  You can read the reviews on Amazon (mostly 5-star).

Comment: I suggest you look up "Harmony of the Gospels".  The earliest is the Diatessaron by Tatian.  However, there have been many more, each reflecting this biases of the authors.  Here is one from Wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_harmony

Comment: Here are some more harmonies of the Gospels: https://www.blueletterbible.org/study/harmony/index.cfm  http://www.lifeofchrist.com/life/harmony/  https://bible.org/article/net-bible-synthetic-harmony-gospels

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.